# vba outlook adding newline between content and signature

Tags: vba, html-email

Hi trying to add a newline between my body content after paste a table and signature,codes are below:

```
dim FileName As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim Outlookmail As Object
Dim lastrowo As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Outlookmail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
lastrowo = Worksheets("Price And Accrued Info").Range("K550").End(xlUp).row
Set rng = Worksheets("Price And Accrued Info").Range("K2:y" & lastrowo)
rng.Copy
Dim vInspector As Object
Set vInspector = Outlookmail.GetInspector

Dim wEditor As Object
Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

With Outlookmail


    .To = ""
    .cc=""
    .Subject = "UNCONFIRMED TRADES AS OF " & Format$(Date, "YYYY.MM.DD")
    wEditor.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Hi The following trades are unconfirmed trades."

    wEditor.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste

    wEditor.Paragraphs(4).Range.Text = vbNewLine & "<br>"


    .display
  ' .attachments.Add drWorkbook.FullName
  ' .attachments.Add crWorkbook.FullName
  '
End With

Set Outlookmail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With Outlookmail
    .To = ""
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = "UNCONFIRMED TRADES AS OF " & Format$(Date, "YYYY.MM.DD")
    wEditor.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Hi The following trades are unconfirmed trades." _
        & String(5, vbNewLine)
    wEditor.Paragraphs(5).Range.Text = "This is is the last line." _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    wEditor.Paragraphs(3).Range.Paste
    .display
End With
```